Blender 4.1: importing SVG and wanted to move it around, only one element per time is possible?
I'm a Blender beginner.
I imported an SVG image (Blender automatically creates a collection) that has several elements.
I select them all, and I go to the right panel, I select "object" and I want to move the WHOLE image on X axis or whatever
The issue is: it move only 1 element of the image and not all the element.
I'm not able to figure out how to move such things.
I lost half hour and then I'm looking for your help please.
here the link to the animated GIF so you see the process


Please add an image of your Blender screen. You can save a screenshot using Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu and then follow How to upload an image to a post. It would also help if you could share your Blend file which you can do via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Sounds like you might have imported as an Grease Pencil object, rather than a bezier curve. Impossible to know without more info

@JohnEason I added a link to an animated GIF that shows you the details.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos not really. I used the import as SVG ... please watch the animated GIF I added.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for the editing to my message.

Excellence in Anti-intuitivity :-/
Once selected all the elements of the imported SVG: right-key Join or CTRL+J
THEN I was able to move and rotate the whole stuff

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/selecting/introduction.html

In the properties tab to the right you only see properties of a single object, the active object (the one with a brighter selection outline) and if you change the values there you only change it for the single object. If you want to move all, hold Alt while changing the values. Or if you want to move all for example 3 m on the X axis, move your mouse into the 3D Viewport and then press G X 3 and left-click or Return to confirm the action.

@TormyVanCool Joining all into one object is not necessary unless you really need that for something. When you join objects, their individual origins get lost and only the one of the active element remains. Also (not relevant in your case though) if you have different objects with different modifiers on them, only the ones of the active element are kept.

Why my question still "closed"???? 16h ago they asked for details. 13h ago I posted the required detail.

@GordonBrinkmann because there is no way to more or rotate all these things together. The "collection" is not something that can be moved (it seems). The only one way I fond is the one I told. What you suggested with GX3 it works but way uncomfortable. Indeed once give GX3, the objects disappears. It's moved somewhere else. Moreover: no way to rotate it on the 3 axis.

@TormyVanCool Sorry, just by saying GX3 the object disappears is nothing where I could start troubleshooting. This should usually work, without your file it is close to impossible to tell what the problem is. Also it seems to me you need to leanr more about basic functions in Blender and/or if this is all too uncomfortable for you, maybe this is not the right software for you. Most people are doing just fine working with shortcuts in the viewport (I would hate to always have to go to the values in the properties tab).

Regarding the closed question: we are all volunteers here, regular users that try to help others in our spare time - so sorry if we are not fast enough for you and have other things to do as well. Apart from that, we told you how to do what you want, if this does not work for some reason, this reason is not apparent from what you said so far... which means, we still need more clarification. And if the methods work and the only problem is that the way it works is too uncomfortable, I do not think we can actually help you.

@GordonBrinkmann I still posting stuff but my question is Closed. The suggestion form the manual, that I knew already and Duarte wanted to remind me, is not working as I need.
I could make work is CTRL+J. Then I move and rotate on any axis. By using any CAD or any Video editor system, I never had issues on the basic actions like this in 30 years :-) I'm becoming crazy: just rotate an object OR, in case of the SVG: a group of objects. By simply selecting  a collection, should I be able to move it around (including rotation) but it doesn't. The rest is visible into the animated GIF.

For moving them altogether with the transform properties in the tab I told you (and the link provided by Duarte tells the same) to hold Alt while changing the values. Did you try that? You only mention G X 3. Apart from that, your GIF does not even show the complete screen (like the top menu bar for example) so we don't know which pivot point you have set (which is important for rotation), also all objects have their origin at the world center no matter where they are placed which can also mess up the rotation.

And yeah, still closed - I already said it to you: we are just simple users doing this in our spare time! We are not everyone all day online here, and questions have to be re-opened by one of the few (volunteer) moderators (doing it in their spare time), so it can happen that nobody who could open the question looks into it for a long time... what is so hard to understand that you have to ask over and over again?

@GordonBrinkmann sorry the ALT I forgot to try. I tried now and it works. Thanks for this hint. Ok also for the thing about the moderators. I read you after I wrote my answer. We were writing together :-)
